# Xquery copy all 'content' of an element (text() + all child nodes) into new element

Tags: xpath, xquery

In Xquery 3.1 I am transforming an XML file (containing data originally held in SQL tables) into another XML file format. Generally it's quite straightforward, but for one particular element I would like to copy the `text()` as well as any `child` nodes and their respective content into a new element. For example, I want to transform the following XML:

```
<table tablename="collections">
  <record id="1">
    <field fieldname="id">1</field>
    <field fieldname="title">Quisque elementum cursus nunc non aliquam</field>
    <field fieldname="desc">Quisque elementum cursus nunc non aliquam; 
        also known under the title <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</i>.<br/> The 
       same author compiled a large encyclopedia <i>Liber de natura 
       rerum,</i> synthesizing much knowledge from his period.</field>
    <field fieldname="author">Thomas de Cantimpré</field>
   </record>
 </table>
```

into:

```
 <list xml:id="collections">
   <item n="1">
    <list>
     <item type="title">Quisque elementum cursus nunc non aliquam</item>
     <item type="desc">Quisque elementum cursus nunc non aliquam; 
        also known under the title <i>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</i>.<br/> The 
       same author compiled a large encyclopedia <i>Liber de natura 
       rerum,</i> synthesizing much knowledge from his period.</item>
     <item type="author">Thomas de Cantimpré</item>
    </list>
    </item>
 </list>
```

In general much of this hasn't posed a problem. However I'm stumped on the problem of getting the `text()` and all `child` nodes inside element `<field fieldname="desc">`. A solution in XPATH has eluded me.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Can you explain why a simple child node selection `node()` doesn't do the job? A `text` node is a child node so I don't understand why you distinguish between "the text() and all child nodes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your verbal description of "all content" would be all child nodes in XPath terminology and text nodes are of course also child nodes of an element, like the child elements are child nodes. To select all child nodes of a container node you just need `node()` in the context of the container node e.g. `/table/record/field[@fieldname="desc"]/node()` selects all child nodes of the `field fieldname="title"` element of your input sample.

Comment: Thanks for this. Somehow I bypassed `node()` thinking it was selecting itself as well as children. Evidently I was wrong :)

Comment: @Aaron your answer was still very useful to me, and will be useful to others who search on this subject... although you've deleted it, you should consider putting it into the comments here for future visitors. Thanks again.

Comment: The difference between `./node()` and `./(*|text())` is that the former selects comments and processing instructions; the latter drops them.